# UIAlertAction font changes on the tap

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I am setting `UIAlertAction` label `attributedText` in order to set custom Font in UIAlertController.It works but when i tap on the `UIAlertAction` it changes its font to default for some time and then disappears. Here is the code

```
let lb = (action.value(forKey: "__representer") as AnyObject)
let label = lb.value(forKey: "label") as? UILabel
label?.attributedText = myMutableString
```

Comment: I would say setting a custom font is not the best idea to modify native UI, just leave it as it is, if it really needs to be styled differently, you might want to implement your own solution, this will probably break sooner or later with future iOS updates

Comment: If you want custom fonts for iOS components then its better to customise or create own control rather than tinkering iOS components

Comment: It would be a lot better if you use a third-party library for this kind of stuff. Modifying the view properties (which are private methods) could lead your app to be rejected (and have glitches like the one you're experiencing right now). Why don't you take a look at [PMAlertController](https://github.com/Codeido/PMAlertController)?

Comment: Any updates on this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think best idea would be to create your own custom alert controller instead of accessing private properties to set your values. Not sure if Apple would accept it or not.

I don't know the solution for your problem but I know the problem which is

**Problem:** When you press `UIAlertAction`'s button it changes its `state`. It behaves just like the `state`s of `UIButton`. So if you know which property you should set for its `highlighted` state then you can set that to solve this issue.